# Printing an extra underscore, I'm not sure why, only happens once before clearing the screen

Tags: c

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    for(;;) {
        FILE *file = fopen("words.txt", "r");
        int amount = 1000;
        char part[amount];
        long wc = 0;
        while(fgets(part, sizeof part, file) != NULL) {
            ++wc;
        }
        char parts[amount][amount];
        srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            rewind(file);
            int sel = rand() % wc + 1;
            for(int j = 0; j < sel; j++) {
                fgets(part, sizeof part, file);
            }
            strcpy(parts[i], part);
        }
        char *string = parts[rand() % amount];
        int length = strlen(string);
        int mask[length];
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            mask[i] = 0;
        }
        int tries = 6;
        int gameend = 0;
        while(gameend == 0) {
            system("cls");
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if(mask[i] == 0) {
                    printf("_");
                } else {
                    printf("%c", string[i]);
                }
            }
            printf("\ntries: %i", tries);
            printf("\n_____");
            printf("\n     |");
            if(tries == 5) {
                printf("\n     o");
            } else if(tries == 4) {
                printf("\n     o");
                printf("\n     |");
            } else if(tries == 3) {
                printf("\n     o");
                printf("\n    /|");
            } else if(tries == 2) {
                printf("\n     o");
                printf("\n    /|\\");
            } else if(tries == 1) {
                printf("\n     o");
                printf("\n    /|\\");
                printf("\n    /");
            } else if(tries == 0) {
                printf("\n     o");
                printf("\n    /|\\");
                printf("\n    /\\");
            }
            char c;
            scanf("%c", &c);
            int acorrect = 0;
            int bcorrect = 1;
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if(string[i] == c) {
                    mask[i] = 1;
                    acorrect = 1;
                }
                if(mask[i] == 0) {
                    bcorrect = 0;
                }
            }
            gameend = bcorrect;
            if(acorrect == 0) {
                if(isalpha(c)) {
                    if(tries > 0) {
                        tries -= 1;
                    } else {
                        gameend = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        system("cls");
        if(tries > 0) {
            printf("you won! the word was: %s", string);
        } else {
            printf("you LOST! the word was: %s", string);
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

If you can tell I'm quite new to C so any help will be appreciated.

This is a game about hangman, you guess words that are located within words.txt

words.txt is formatted like this:

*word1*
*word2*
*word3*
*word4*
*word5*

https://gyazo.com/8777d7176802eca1f9347143ee05c894

As you see from this video, it adds an extra underscore but removes it once the screen is cleared. The issue does not appear on the second word.

Comment: You haven't actually explained what the code is trying to do.

Comment: Oh I apologize I seem to have deleted that part, I will fix it.

Comment: It's not clear from the video what the issue is. It would be better if you try to explain in words. But one likely  problem is this `scanf("%c", &c);`. `%c` will read all characters including spaces and newline characters. Every time you enter a letter you are actually also entering a newline which will be read by the next `scanf`. Change to `scanf(" %c", &c);` to skip all whitespaces.

Comment: There are 5 underscores in the video where I haven't guessed the letters, as soon as I put "a" it changed to four, which is the true amount of letters in the word, but at the end of the video on the second word, it does not change which is what I desire to happen.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69669719/edit) the post to update it with that info. And did you try with the `scanf` changed?

Comment: yes, and it worked, thank you. You were an awesome help.

Comment: Voting to close with above duplicate - to resolve this post and for future readers.